# When I share my website on certain platforms, there is no preview

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

As stated in the title, when I share my website on platforms like Discord, Facebook, etc., there is no preview available. Does anyone know the reason behind this or how to resolve it?

For instance, when a tweet from Twitter is shared on Discord, it appears like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eidRC.png)

When a page from my website is shared, it only appears as a simple link without any preview or information.

Thats my meta name codes:

```
> header -->
><!DOCTYPE html>
>     <html lang="en" class="fancybox-enabled">
>     <head>
>     <meta charset="UTF-8">
>     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
>     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
>     <title>mywebsite name | pagename blabla</title>
>     <meta name="description" content="&#34;blabla ..&#34;
> pagecontent">
>     <meta name="keywords" content="">
>     <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
>     <meta name="revisit-after" content="7 Days">
>     <link rel="icon" href="/logo.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

How should these codes be?

I tried meta name and it doesn't work.

Comment: Facebook and other platforms use [Open Graph](https://ogp.me/) meta tags for information about your site. If you do not provide og tags, most platforms will use other information from your site to create a preview. OG tags use a property/content pairing, while Twitter uses a name/content pairing, if you want separate twitter tags.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I tried meta name and it doesn't work."*?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have better luck if you use Open Graph tagging.  From [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup):

```
<meta property="og:url"                content="http://www.nytimes.com/2015/02/19/arts/international/when-great-minds-dont-think-alike.html" />
<meta property="og:type"               content="article" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="When Great Minds Don’t Think Alike" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="How much does culture influence creative thinking?" />
<meta property="og:image"              content="http://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/02/19/arts/international/19iht-btnumbers19A/19iht-btnumbers19A-facebookJumbo-v2.jpg" />
```

Comment: thnx for answer ill try it but i knew discord doesn't need og tag

Comment: Note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: @Rob Yeah, yeah, some of us like it there for comfort from the enlightened civilized time of XHTML. ;-)  In any case, it's just a copy/paste from the docs, and no HTML specification that I know of disallows comfort closing slashes.  Besides, for anyone using minification, it'll be wiped out anyway.  ;-)

Comment: The W3C validator now flags it. But I, too, was a strong believe in xml and xhtml.